# Error message in Monaca debug mode with Onsen UI Angular 2

Tags: cordova, angular, webpack, monaca, onsen-ui2

I’m having template parse errors in Monaca debugger. When using `monaca preview`, it is running in the browser without any problem, but when I use `monaca debug`, I see “Error: Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'ngif' since it isn't a known property of 'span'.” in the Applog. I have carefully checked, the error is caused by “*ngif” directive.

I've also checked - all Angular directives also cause the same issue.

I attached screenshots of the Applog.

[image: 1_1476975967061_Screenshot_2016-10-20-16-03-47.png]

[image: 0_1476975967059_Screenshot_2016-10-20-15-19-11.png]

I have [cross posted this here](https://community.onsen.io/topic/966/error-message-in-monaca-debug-mode-with-onsen-ui-angular-2).

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the error is caused because a post-processor in monaca lowercases the HTML directives. Eg: from `*ngIf` to `*ngif`. _Notice the lowercase 'i'_; check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38533535/1937344)

Comment: I'm currently tracing the issue. The `HtmlWebpackPlugin` seems to be the issue...

Comment: Now using a temporary/hacky solution: I wrap the html containing a case-sensitive directive with `<!-- htmlmin:ignore -->` so that it can be skipped during minification. See the [documentation](https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier#ignoring-chunks-of-markup). Still expecting a final solution though.

Comment: Have this ever been solved? if not can you give an example code with ignore part

Comment: @Skipper, simply wrap the HTML section that contains the directive with `<!-- htmlmin:ignore -->` _(as opening and closing tags)_ and re-run your project. I think you can also disable minification of HTML files (but I advise against it)

Answer (score 0):

You should have 2 webpack config files, development and production. `webpack.prod.config.js` is using HTMLWebpackPlugin for minifying the HTML. Simply add `caseSentisive: true` option to the minify configuration (around line 120). All the options for HTMLWebpackPlugin [here](https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin#configuration) and its minifier [here](https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier#options-quick-reference).

I just added this option to the default template. Hope it helps!

Comment: Nice point but it still ain't working. Please take a spin for yourself. You can use Onsen UI's default templates as the base.

Answer (score -1):

Set `useAsDefault: true` in the child routing of `application.route.ts`.

I.e. we have to specify which route is to be open by default.

Comment: This is an Onsen UI mobile application. I think that routing is handled internally by `OnsenModule`.