# Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'div' in production build

Tags: angular

I can able to run through locally. Getting error only in production build.

I have used

```
 import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
 imports:      [  CommonModule ]
```

Full error is shown below.

```
client:101 Template parse errors:enter code here`Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. 
("move" class="transport-remove">Remove</a></div>
         <div id="carTypeDiv_1" class="veh-inv-out" [ERROR ->]*ngIf="vehicleData.vesselType == 'road'">
            <ul id="carTypeList_1" class="veh-slides">
    "): VehicleDirective@10:52
Property binding ngIf not used by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly and all directives are listed in the "@NgModule.declarations". ("t:" (click)="removeField($event)" title="Remove" class="transport-remove">Remove</a></div>
         [ERROR ->]<div id="carTypeDiv_1" class="veh-inv-out" *ngIf="vehicleData.vesselType == 'road'">
            <ul "): VehicleDirective@10:9
Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'option'. ("l)]="vehicleData.makeSelect" (change)="appendModel($event.target.value)">
                  <option [ERROR ->]*ngFor="let make of vehicle.makes">{{make}}</option>
               </select>
            </div>
"): VehicleDirective@28:26
Property binding ngForOf not used by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly and all directives are listed in the "@NgModule.declarations". ("[(ngModel)]="vehicleData.makeSelect" (change)="appendModel($event.target.value)">
                  [ERROR ->]<option *ngFor="let make of vehicle.makes">{{make}}</option>
               </select>
            </d"): VehicleDirective@28:18
Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'option'. ("t" id="modelSelect" [(ngModel)]="vehicleData.modelSelect" class="prefixbox">
               <option [ERROR ->]*ngFor="let model of vehicle.models">{{model}}</option>
            </select></div>
            <br c"): VehicleDirective@36:23
Property binding ngForOf not used by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly and all directives are listed in the "@NgModule.declarations". ("delSelect" id="modelSelect" [(ngModel)]="vehicleData.modelSelect" class="prefixbox">
               [ERROR ->]<option *ngFor="let model of vehicle.models">{{model}}</option>
            </select></div>
         "): VehicleDirective@36:15
Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'option'. ("refixbox">
                        <option value="">SELECT</option>
                        <option [ERROR ->]*ngFor="let year of vehicle.years">{{year}}</option>
                     </select>
                 "): VehicleDirective@47:32
Property binding ngForOf not used by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly and all directives are listed in the "@NgModule.declarations". ("class="prefixbox">
                        <option value="">SELECT</option>
                        [ERROR ->]<option *ngFor="let year of vehicle.years">{{year}}</option>
                     </select>
         "): VehicleDirective@47:24
Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'option'. ("ateSelect" [(ngModel)]="vehicleData.stateSelect" class="prefixbox">
                        <option [ERROR ->]*ngFor="let state of vehicle.regStates">{{state}}</option>
                     </select>
           "): VehicleDirective@55:32
Property binding ngForOf not used by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly and all directives are listed in the "@NgModule.declarations". ("" id="stateSelect" [(ngModel)]="vehicleData.stateSelect" class="prefixbox">
                        [ERROR ->]<option *ngFor="let state of vehicle.regStates">{{state}}</option>
                     </select>
   "): VehicleDirective@55:24
Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'option'. ("lorSelect" [(ngModel)]="vehicleData.colorSelect" class="prefixbox">
                        <option [ERROR ->]*ngFor="let color of vehicle.colors">{{color}}</option>
                     </select>
              "): VehicleDirective@68:32
Property binding ngForOf not used by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly and all directives are listed in the "@NgModule.declarations". ("" id="colorSelect" [(ngModel)]="vehicleData.colorSelect" class="prefixbox">
                        [ERROR ->]<option *ngFor="let color of vehicle.colors">{{color}}</option>
                     </select>
      "): VehicleDirective@68:24
```

What is the reason. I have verified many solution. could not find the soultion. Same code is working fine with local.

Comment: Add Your HTML template code where you have use ngIf on div element

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39058075/cant-bind-to-ngif-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-div)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

After adding browser module its working fine.

```
 import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
 @NgModule({
     imports: [BrowserModule ]
  })
```

Comment: It really looks like Angular's error handling could 'know' (or guess) that ngIf is one of it's own directives, and 'know' that it is in BrowserModule. The error message in the browser console could suggest 'Have you imported BrowserModule'? Probably the biggest shortcoming in Angular IMHO is the error messages can be less than helpful when things go wrong.

Comment: Leave it to Angular where you need to close your eyes, touch your nose, and hop on your left foot to make a default feature work properly.

Answer (score 99):

I had exactly the same error, and I had included both CommonModule and  BrowserModule and yet I still saw the same error message on my browser.

Finally, I found the cause of my problem was that I forgot to add my component to app.module.ts, in case someone else is dealing with the same behavior.

**EDIT**: this problem can be solved also by adding the component to one of the modules **imported** by app.module.ts.

Comment: This worked for me! Thanks so much for mentioning this!!! Can't believe this isn't a more accepted answer. By the way, if you're wondering where, it should be in imports: imports: [..., ModalPageModule],

Comment: The error message is so bad, how are we supposed to find this lol. Thanks!

Comment: I think this is the best answer. Thanks, man!

Comment: After going through all the posts. Finally read this comment and I felt dumb not to check app.modules.ts. Thanks for the answer

Comment: great, it was my issue as well and this solved it

Comment: 99% of my problems are forgetting this and forgetting that.. is this an angular probem or what !!

Comment: Thank you for this answer, while my component was in its module, the module it belonged to wasn't in the app module and had me spinning my wheels for quite a while.

Comment: Same issue here (forgetting to add component into app.module declarations). What a strange red herring error message!

Comment: This stumped me for quite some time. I completely forgot to add it to the declarations.

Comment: If it still don't work and your hot reloading then abort and compile again.

Comment: In my case I had to import the module in which the component was declared

Answer (score 38):

This error can also occur if your component is NOT included in the `declarations` section of the module:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';            // <-- required

import { InventoryRoutingModule } from './inventory-routing.module';
import { InventoryComponent } from './pages/inventory/inventory.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [InventoryComponent],                      // <-- In my case, this was missing
  imports: [CommonModule, InventoryRoutingModule]
})
export class InventoryModule {}
```

Comment: You saved my day. Common mistake, and I spend 1 hour for googling a proper solution.

Comment: Thank you sir, this has to have more upvotes i guess

Comment: I wasted 1 hour on this, thanks for saving me a few more ...

Comment: I was pulling my hair out until I found this. Nothing else worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I had this error in one my unit tests; seems I needed to include a child component in the TestBed config. This answer got me to the solution.

Answer (score 18):

Other solution if none of the above works is just to restart your `ng serve`, that worked for me. Or maybe try this method first before pulling your hairs out.

PS: This is not the OP's issue as he's on production, this is only for development environment.

Comment: I run into this issue and it did be solved after restart `ng serve`!

Comment: Same for me. I moved a form control into another component and started getting the `ngIf` error. Rebooting the dev server fixed. Thanks.

Comment: Works combined with dist + node_modules folders deletion

Answer (score 11):

You should add CommonModule either in the root component or the related component,

```js
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
```

Also, add `CommonModule` to the `imports` property of @NgModule and your component to the `declarations` property.

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
  })
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I already had a component with the same name in app.module.ts, which led to my new component not being parsed correctly and resulting in "can't bind to 'ngIf'", basically same issue as above with missing declaration in app.module.ts

solution:

existing component:

```
import { DialogComponent } from './common/button-popup/dialog/dialog.component';
```

I had to add an alias for the new component

```
import { DialogComponent } from './common/button-popup/dialog/dialog.component';
import { DialogComponent as DialogGenericComponent } from './common/dialog/dialog.component';
```

Answer (score 2):

if your project working fine but underline with the error.
update **Angular language service** extension.
to update press Ctrl + Shift + x and search **Angular language service** then update the extension and reload through the extension

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If your component is standalone
for ex -

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-delete-alert',
templateUrl: './delete-alert.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./delete-alert.component.scss'],
standalone: true,
})
```

Then import CommonModule in the same file.

```
    import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';    
    @Component({
    selector: 'app-delete-alert',
    templateUrl: './delete-alert.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./delete-alert.component.scss'],
    standalone: true,
    imports:[CommonModule]
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are great. I have a variation on the common answer (import `CommonModule`), an alternative answer and wanted to link [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/extended-diagnostics/NG8103#how-to-fix-the-problem) which captures my error.

I updated to Angular 17 and got this error.
My alternative solution is to use the new Angular "control flow directives" like `@if(...)` instead of `*ngIf="..."`

Old:

```
template: `<div *ngIf="visible">Hi</div>`,
```

New:

```
template: `@if (visible) { <div>Hi</div> }`,
```

If you're not ready for that, another solution is to "make sure that a corresponding control flow directive is imported." For me it was important to do two things

1. import into the Component `imports` property themselves (vs the parent Modules)
2. declare that Component as `standalone: true`

I could import `NgIf`

> A directive can be imported individually:
>
> ```
> import {NgIf} from '@angular/common';
> ...
> imports: [NgIf],
> ```

... or `CommonModule`

> ...or you could import the entire [`CommonModule`](https://angular.io/api/common/CommonModule), which contains all control flow directives:
>
> ```
> import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
> ...
> imports: [CommonModule],
> ```

Maybe I need to use `standalone: true` since the creation of ["standalone components"](https://angular.io/guide/standalone-components) More [here](https://angular.io/guide/standalone-components#using-existing-ngmodules-in-a-standalone-component):

> When writing a standalone component, you may want to use other components, directives, or pipes in the component's template. Some of those dependencies might not be marked as standalone, but instead declared and exported by an existing `NgModule`. In this case, **you can import the `NgModule` directly into the standalone component**...

So my component looks like this:

```
import { CommonModule, NgIf } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
    selector: 'craft-login-form',
    templateUrl: './login-form.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./login-form.component.scss'],
    standalone: true,
    imports: [
        NgIf
    ],
})
```