# ngIf not working. Even if I do *ngIf="true" it doesn't show, neither does *ngIf="false"

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-directive, angular-ng-if

I want hide a div if some variable is `null`, but `*ngIf` is not working even if I assign true directly.

`tree.component.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Tree} from '../model/tree';
import { TreeService } from '../service/tree.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tree',
  templateUrl: './tree.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tree.component.css']
})
export class TreeComponent implements OnInit {

  canShow: boolean = true;
  tree!: Tree;

  constructor(private treeService:TreeService) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.tree= this.treeService.returnTree();
  }

}
```

`tree.component.html`

```
...

          <div *ngIf="canShow">
            <h1 class="sm:text-2xl font-medium mb-2 text-gray-900">Significado dos nomes populares</h1>
            <p class="pb-3 leading-relaxed text-gray-500">{{tree.nameMeaning}}</p>
          </div>
...
```

`tree.component.html`

```
...

          <div *ngIf="true">
            <h1 class="sm:text-2xl font-medium mb-2 text-gray-900">Significado dos nomes populares</h1>
            <p class="pb-3 leading-relaxed text-gray-500">{{tree.nameMeaning}}</p>
          </div>
...
```

Error in console:

```
NG0303: Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'h2'.
```

Solution by [psyklopz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1017107/psyklopz) at [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42063686/cant-bind-to-ngif-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-div-in-production-buil)

I've imported `TreeComponent` into `@NgModule` `declarations` of `app.module.ts`.

Comment: Check the parent elements, maybe you have another `ngIf` that prevents this markup to be rendered.

Comment: 2 likely causes. 1) You have a fatal exception somewhere, view the console output in your browser to see if there are Exceptions being thrown. 2) You are looking at the wrong rendered component or output. Add something temporary but identifying to it to verify what it is you are seeing.

Comment: It seems to be working now.

Error in console: `NG0303: Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'h2'.`

Solution: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39058075/cant-bind-to-ngif-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-div).

I've imported `TreeComponent` into `@NgModule` of `app.module.ts`.

Answer (score 1):

### `ngIf` requires the CommonModule in Angular

Install the `CommonModule` into the parent module of your component, as it has the `ngIf` directive. I did not see that imported in your example.

```
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule]
})
```

Comment: Also if you have imported the BrowserModule you should also get these directives.

Answer (score 0):

Also if you're trying to put this stuff in an `<ng-container>` tag, make sure your tag is actually called `ng-container` NOT some other tag that doesn't exist like `ng-component`.